# Processing JSON arrays

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a JSON file arranged in this pattern:

```
[
{
"Title ID": "4224031",
"Overtime Status": "Non-Exempt",
"Shift rates": "No Shift rates",
"On call rates": "No On call rates"
},
[
{
"Step: 1.0": [
"$38.87",
"(38.870000)"
]
}
]
][
{
"Title ID": "4225031",
"Overtime Status": "Non-Exempt",
"Shift rates": "No Shift rates",
"On call rates": "No On call rates"
},
[
{
"Step: 1.0": [
"$38.87",
"(38.870000)"
]
}
]
]
```

I am trying to get it into a Pandas DataFrame. I have tried opening a connection to the JSON file and running JSON.load(s). Unfortunately, I get JSON decode errors like: "JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 16 column 2 (char 182)". When running the JSON through a linter, I see that there might be an issue with the way the JSON is presented in the file. The parts between the brackets are valid but when wrapped in brackets, become invalid. I have then tried to get at the dictionaries with the wrapping brackets but have not been able to make much progress. Does anyone have tips on how I can successfully access this JSON data and get it into a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

The json is invalid beacuase it has more than one root in this representation.
This has to be like this

`jsonObject = [{"1":"3"}], [{"4":"5"}]`

Hacks that I am able to think of are replace these brackets `][` to this  `],[`  by find and replace in editor. You'll be able to then create a dataframe as its a list now.

Second, if its not a one time job, then you need to write a regex that can do this for you in text cleaning pipeline(or code). I'm not good at writing of working regex(sorry mate).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

First, after examining the JSON data in a linter, I found that I had some extra brackets and braces at different points. So, I am running the data through a regex that cleans out the unnecessary brackets and braces.

Next, I run each line, which now looks like a string dictionary through json.loads

Finally, I call pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data)) to get my desired pandas dataframe.

Thanks for the help from commenters.